# Multiloop feedback control system find closed loop gain

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory

I want to find the closed loop gain of this block diagram:

[image]

I remember a rule that since these 2 loops collide with each other we ignore them so is the closed loop gain just equal to $\frac{H_{1}(s)}{1+H_{1}(s)H_{2}(s)}$?

Comment: Homework?  What have you done to try to solve this so far?

Comment: @TimWescott I am preparing for a exam.And I have already posted a guess the answer should be Y/N.

Comment: Is there a source for this block diagram ? A signal line where signal flows in *two* directions is not usually seen in text books. This diagram may simply be *wrong*. Please provide a source.

Comment: I didn't consider that making a wild guess (and a wrong one, at that) shows enough effort.  Something like the answer below, with a math error in the middle -- **that** counts as effort, and worthy of effort on my part.

Answer (score 1):

I've redrawn your diagram below and added some of my own labels:

[image]

We can then find an expression for $Y(s)/U(s)$ as follows:
\begin{align}
Y(s) &= X_1(s) - X_2(s) \\
&= H_1(s)X_3(s) - H_2(s)Y(s) \\
&= H_1(s)(U(s) - X_2(s)) - H_2(s)Y(s) \\
&= H_1(s)U(s) - H_1(s)X_2(s) - H_2(s)Y(s) \\
&= H_1(s)U(s) - H_1(s)(H_2(s)Y(s)) - H_2(s)Y(s) \\
&= H_1(s)U(s) - H_1(s)H_2(s)Y(s) - H_2(s)Y(s) \\
Y(s) + H_1(s)H_2(s)Y(s) + H_2(s)Y(s) &= H_1(s)U(s) \\
(1 + H_1(s)H_2(s) + H_2(s))Y(s) &= H_1(s)U(s) \\
\frac{Y(s)}{U(s)} &= \frac{H_1(s)}{1 + H_1(s)H_2(s) + H_2(s)} \\
\end{align}
The general strategy for dealing with block diagrams is to make sure that all inputs and outputs of summing junctions are labelled, and then we can express all labelled signals as a function of either $Y(s)$ or $U(s)$. We then solve for $Y(s)/U(s)$.

Comment: Note that this is the "brute force" method for reducing a block diagram.  It always works, so you should know it in the event that block diagram reduction fails.  _If_ you're doing a lot of block diagram reduction, then memorizing all the rules for it is helpful -- but those rules don't cover all the cases, and sometimes you'll end up doing more work than if you just write out the math.

Comment: @TimWescott I think the “brute-force” method is not emphasized enough when first learning about block diagram reduction for the first time. In my experience I learned the basic block diagram reduction techniques and had to memorize them, but knowing the brute-force method after a long time was illuminating.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's not emphasized enough, or if people just forget it because they've memorized a table of rules to get through an exam.  But -- the **value** can't be emphasized more, for sure. If I've been away from control systems for a while and need to reduce block diagrams, I check my reduction skills using the brute-force method.